# Responsividade Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, layout-responsivo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesse simulador de empréstimos, preciso que ele fique bem responsivo, mas quando eu reduzo a tela dele, os select's dele não fica um abaixo do outro.

Isso é um template.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Romulo teria como vc postar o código do arquivo, html e css, ai fica mais fácil para te ajudar

Answer (score 1):

Da um `align="center"` na `div` dos `selects`.

Vai ficar assim:
`<div align="center" class="">`

Comment: Deu certo aqui o `<input>` estava quebrando. Mas agora quando está em versão desktop ele quebra. Os `<select>` não ficar proporcionais.